# Django redirect users based on group upon login

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect users in a particular group to a particular template and those not in it to the dashboard when they login. What I've done currently keeps bringing up the http response for users not in the group whenever I try to login with a user in the group.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Profile
from .decorators import allowed_users
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html')

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('Username')
        password = request.POST.get('Password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(username,password,user)
        if user is None:
            messages.success(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            if group == 'Hospitals':
                
                return redirect('core/hospital.html')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorised to access this page')

            login(request, user)

            return redirect('dashboard')
```

Comment: last 2 lines in the else block are unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually log the user in, like ever. I expect you want it to be something like this:

```
  ...
        else:
            login(request, user)
            group = None
            if user.groups.exists():
                group = user.groups.all()[0].name
            if group == 'Hospitals':
                return redirect('core/hospital.html')
            return redirect('dashboard')
```